# Efficient way to convert <List<List<StrongType.String>> to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection that consists of `List<List<MyType>>` and I'm looking at creating a list of string from this.

Where MyType is :

```
class MyType
{
   public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

I want to end up with a flat list of strings, using linq in an efficient way without using a for loop.

Above the property is Description I'm working with.

Comment: What means "effificient without for-loop". Be aware that in order to achieve this task you *have* to iterate the lists in any way, so no matter on how you beautify the code the iterations will remain.

Comment: AFAIK the most efficient (in terms of speed) way to iterate a list is using the old-plain indexed for-loop. I wonder why you don't want to use it.

Comment: @MarioVernari not always true, iterators are awesome if used correclty

Comment: @bto.rdz please clarify what you mean for "correctly". Could you make some example where iterators are faster than indexers?

Comment: @MarioVernari With my example you only have 1 list in memory, if you use indexers you have 2 options, 1) use a nested for, which in my opinion will not be as easy to read compared with a linq query, 2) copy the elements to a second list and with it double memory usage.

Comment: @bto.rdz Let's say that English is not my language, but the question stated "an efficient", not "elegant": these are going in opposite directions! I'm with you about readiness of the Linq, but the classic way is way faster. Have a try:https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EC4CBA2ED0D68D68!4881&authkey=!AHq-B8sFEYzpue8&ithint=file%2ccs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
List<List<MyType>> list = //your list....

var result = list.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.Description));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `List<List<MyType>>` is named `MyList`:

```
List<string> strings = (from myTypes in MyList 
                                    from myType in myTypes 
                                    select myType.Description
                        ).ToList();
```

---

If you want to avoid duplicates in a single shot:

```
HashSet<string> myHashSet = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (MyType myType in MyList.SelectMany(myTypes => myTypes))
{
    myHashSet.Add(myType.Description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:

```
var list = SelectMany(x => x).Select(x => x.Description).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourList.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.Description)).ToList();
```